# Navigation Drawer - How to add items at run-time to an existing menu group

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have this existing group, called `group0`, defined in xml:

```
<group android:id="@+id/group0"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
</group>
```

I want to add more options to it:

```
nav_view.menu.add(groupId = R.id.group0, itemId = 85621, order = 12345, title = "adding to group 0")
```

Despite of the `targetGroup` parameter, this does not add to `group0`. I can confirm this by removing everything in `group0`:

```
nav_view.menu.removeGroup(R.id.group0)
```

The new item is not removed. It also does not share the `checkableBehavior` defined in XML.

How can I programmatically add new items to an existing group?

Answer (score 0):

After reading Android source code, I think I got an idea for the problems here.

The new item was indeed added to `group0` as advertised. It can be verified through its `groupId` property. But it doesn't behave like one. This appears to be 2 separate issues I was having.

1. Item is not removed when the group is removed.

This turns out to be a combination of misconfiguration and android bug. In the source code of `removeGroup(int groupId)` method, android starts iterating each menu item and checks its `groupId`. But it aborts the process if the next item no longer belongs to the target group. This is an acceptable optimization assuming all items in the same group will show up next to each other in the navigation drawer. The "misconfiguration" here is that I passed in a large integer for `order`, making my item show up much later down the list.

The solution here is to pass `0` for `order` parameter when adding the menu item, so they show up next to existing items in the group. Alternatively, override `removeGroup` function and remove the "optimization" code.

2. Item does not share the `checkableBehavior` defined by the group in XML.

This is because `isCheckable` is actually a property for each menu item, instead of a group property. So when new items are added, they do not automatically have `isCheckable` set correctly (although technically the `add` method in Android could have easily done it for us).

The solution here is to call `isCheckable = true` on each of the newly added item.